# When should I clean the applications' temp files?

Tags: android, caching, storage, temporary-files

I am writing an application and using some temporary files in internal storage e.g. (`/myapp/files/tmp/*`)

The files are temporary and are  considered expired when the application exits.
What are some good practices for cleaning up such files?

There is no `onDestroy()` in Application class. Interchanging between activies means it's not trivial to know when an activity's `onDestroy` is exiting the activity, or application. Furthermore, none of these will get called when the application crashes, for instance. They are not guaranteed to be called.

So I am cleaning those files in `onCreate` in my instance of the Application class (in an `AsyncTask` launched at `onCreate`).

But it seems a little quirky to me. Launching the application will launch a thread to delete unnecessary files from previous usage. Is there a better way to do this?

`file.deleteOnExit()` is also discouraged on Android

Comment: you can override  onTerminate() of Application class.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia onTerminate()  seems like a very, very bad idea:
"This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so. "

Comment: so when you want to remove your temp files? when app goes to background?

Comment: I'd like them to be removed as soon as they are not needed anymore, meaning as soon as the application exits and the vm terminates. (Not when the app gets minimized) 

I was generally asking for good practices or tricks for file cache management - like a temp folder that gets created and deleted when application gets started/exited, or something like file.deleteOnExit() which would work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using activity's life cycle.

Follow the steps.

1) Create BaseActivity.java which extends Activity or FragmentActivity.

2) All other activity will extends  BaseActivity.

3) Now you need to override two methods say

onResume();

onPause();

4) How your base activity looks like.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public static int actictyCounter=0;


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        actictyCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        actictyCounter--;

        // This was the last activity 
        if(actictyCounter==0){
            //code to remove your temp files
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a horrible way to track whether my application is running or not. Static mutable data counting all activities? No way in hell I am doing this. I am not going to down vote your answer, because it can be done this way and you've put some effort in showing it, but I will not accept this as an answer.

Comment: ok dude not an issue whenever you found the better solution than update my answer.